# Spring ws & multiple schemas

Tags: java, spring-ws

I have spring configuration in my servlet...

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.knowledgebase.webservice"/>
<sws:annotation-driven/>

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="carService"
                  portTypeName="carService"
                  locationUri="/carService/">
    <sws:xsd location="classpath:/wsDefinition/car/properties.xsd"/>
    <sws:xsd location="classpath:/wsDefinition/car/carServiceSimple.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and two XSDs in the same folder - carServiceSimple.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:pro="http://bar.foo/properties"
       targetNamespace="http://bar.foo"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:import schemaLocation="properties.xsd" namespace="http://bar.foo/properties"/>

<xs:element name="StoreCarRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Properties" type="pro:PropertiesType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="StoreCarResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="UpdateCarRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Properties" type="pro:PropertiesType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="UpdateCarResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

- properties.xsd:

But after deploying on Glassfish 3, the exception is arisen: Multiple  elements requires Commons XMLSchema.Please put Commons XMLSchema on the classpath.

Spring ws doc section 5.3.1:
If you want to use multiple schemas, either by includes or imports, you will want to put Commons XMLSchema on the class path. If Commons XMLSchema is on the class path, the above  element will follow all XSD imports and includes, and will inline them in the WSDL as a single XSD.

What does "Commons XMLSchema" mean? How can I fix it? Thx.

I have both XSD files on the classpath (in war: WEB-INF\classes\wsDefinition\car). When I remove line  from servlet, then is generated wsdl accessible, but when I want create SoapUI project base on this wsdl, the SopaUI shows error: is not possible find properties.xsd.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to include the jar file for the [Commons XMLSchema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema/) project in your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: Upps it is library, thank you beny23. It was my the most stupid question. Probably it was too late when I got this error.

Answer (score 3):

If someone lands here... add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```